# FROM_HEX in Google BigQuery returns different result than the result on the public documentation

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having a hard time with this function which doesn't seem to work as specified in the Google BigQuery (standard syntax) [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#from_hex). This is how it should work:

```
WITH Input AS (SELECT '00010203aaeeefff' AS hex_str)
SELECT hex_str, FROM_HEX(hex_str) AS bytes_str
FROM Input;

hex_str          | bytes_str
0AF              | \x00\xaf
```

What I actually see is:

```
hex_str          | bytes_str
0AF              | AK8=
```

Clearly not the same, but I have no idea why. Possibly some GBQ encoding setting that isn't specified - I'm following the reference exactly.

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT '00010203aaeeefff' AS hex_str UNION ALL
  SELECT '0AF' UNION ALL
  SELECT '666f6f626172'
)
SELECT hex_str, FROM_HEX(hex_str) AS bytes_str, FORMAT("%t", FROM_HEX(hex_str)) AS format_string
FROM Input;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect you're seeing is that the BigQuery UI shows the base64 encoding of `BYTES` values, so the results appear to be incorrect. What you can do instead is to convert the `BYTES` values to string in order to display them:

```
WITH Input AS (SELECT '00010203aaeeefff' AS hex_str)
SELECT hex_str, SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING(FROM_HEX(hex_str)) AS bytes_str
FROM Input;
```